# Double Subsection title

Tags: sectioning, section-titles

I'm working on a "report" which consists of the solutions for several assignments which are structured into "topics" and "parts". 
I'm quite happy with the result I got by simply using sections (with title equal to topic name) and I redefined the subsection command with `\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{Part \arabic{subsection}}`. Which works fine. 
But right now I would like to merge the answer of two parts into one. Is it possible to start one subsection as "**Part 2&3**"?

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{Part \arabic{subsection}}

\begin{document}
\section{Polytropes}
The code used for the computations in this section can be seen in Appendix 1.
\subsection{}
\textbf{ASSIGNMENT}\\
my solution.
\subsection{and 3} %this obviously horrible due to spacing, referencing, counter, etc. 
\textbf{ASSIGNMENT of part 2 and 3}\\
my solution.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX-SX! As a new member, it is recommended to visit the [Welcome](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) and the [Tour](https://tex.stackexchange.com/tour) pages to be informed about our format and also to know about [Minimal Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228). 
Otherwise, more specifically about your question: a Minimal Example would help to illustrate and clarify your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd avoid overloading `\subsection` and define a proper command based on it. In the code, instead of a numbered section, I use `\subsection*` and pass the expected title, setting `\@currentlabel`, which is responsible for the correct cross reference.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\documentpart}{%
  \stepcounter{subsection}%
  \def\@currentlabel{Part \arabic{subsection}}%
  \subsection*{\@currentlabel}%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{\@currentlabel}%
}
\newcommand{\extradocumentpart}{%
  \stepcounter{subsection}%
  \def\@currentlabel{Part \@arabic{\c@subsection} and \@arabic{\numexpr\c@subsection+1\relax}}%
  \subsection*{\@currentlabel}
  \addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{\@currentlabel}%
  \stepcounter{subsection}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{Polytropes}

The code used for the computations in this section can be seen in Appendix~1.

\documentpart\label{test1}
\textbf{ASSIGNMENT of \ref{test1}}\\
my solution.

\extradocumentpart\label{test2}
\textbf{ASSIGNMENT of \ref{test2}}\\
my solution.

\documentpart\label{test3}
\textbf{ASSIGNMENT of \ref{test3}}\\
my solution.

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you also want actual titles

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\documentpart}[1]{%
  \stepcounter{subsection}%
  \def\@currentlabel{Part \arabic{subsection}}%
  \subsection*{\@currentlabel\quad#1}%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{\@currentlabel\quad#1}%
}
\newcommand{\extradocumentpart}[1]{%
  \stepcounter{subsection}%
  \def\@currentlabel{Part \@arabic{\c@subsection} and \@arabic{\numexpr\c@subsection+1\relax}}%
  \subsection*{\@currentlabel\quad#1}
  \addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{\@currentlabel\quad#1}%
  \stepcounter{subsection}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{Polytropes}

The code used for the computations in this section can be seen in Appendix~1.

\documentpart{Some title}\label{test1}
\textbf{ASSIGNMENT of \ref{test1}}\\
my solution.

\extradocumentpart{Some title}\label{test2}
\textbf{ASSIGNMENT of \ref{test2}}\\
my solution.

\documentpart{Some title}\label{test3}
\textbf{ASSIGNMENT of \ref{test3}}\\
my solution.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much!
This definitely works!
There is a small peculiarity though: in the toc, the "dots" seem to ignore the numbers (in this case "2 and 3" has the dots just underneath it)

Comment: @Andrej Revamped code, now there is no problem with the toc.

Comment: Thank you very much!!! (edit because I typed my answer while you already enhanced the code)
Is it possible to add the possibility of a title to the `\documentpart` command?

Comment: changing it to `\newcommand{\documentpart}[1]{%
 \stepcounter{subsection}%
 \def\@currentlabel{Part \arabic{subsection}\hspace{1em}#1}` allows to add a title, but then the referencing gets messy as it also includes the title into the reference...

Comment: @Andrej I can't read your mind, sorry. Did you speak about titles?

Comment: No I didn't... This was just a follow-up question. And I'm already very thankful as it does everything I wanted from it! Not sure what you mean with "I can't read your mind". If it's because of my "edit because [...]". I wrote it because originally my response said something else and I then edited it.

Comment: @Andrej I added the support for titles. Probably I'll add a more compact version.

Comment: Thank you very very much! I would upvote you multiple times if I could. (Though my votes aren't visible anyway)